# Surat Al-Mulk Grave torture savior by the will of Allah

Tags: quran, death, punishment, grave

Brothers can you please confirm this, i have recently found out that memorizing surat al mulk and reciting it every night will save us from the grave torture, what ahadith is there to support this my brothers and sisters?

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hspCap2jniw)

Answer (score 1):

The narration it mentions is a saying of Abdullah bin Masoud and not the Prophets.  It goes as follows, Abdullah bin Masoud said =

> من قرأ تبارك الذي بيده الملك كل ليلة منعه الله بها من عذاب القبر
>
> "Whoever reads 'Tabaraka allathee biyadihialmulk' every night, Allah
>   will protect him from the torment of the grave..."

Recorded in *Sunan alKubra* of Imam an-Nasai and it's not a saying of the Prophet and it's inauthentic anyways.

Two narrators are problematic.  First is **عرفجة بن عبد الواحد** who was not known to report hadith and any narrations related to him weren't taken unless there were other authentic ones to back him up.

Second problem is **عاصم بن بهدلة** who was a pious person and a reciter of the Quran.  Yet, in *hadith* he wasn't strong and made mistakes.  But even if his reports are accepted, **عرفجة بن عبد الواحد** aren't.

There are similar hadiths attributed to the Prophet =

> إِنَّ سُورَةً مِنَ الْقُرْآنِ ثَلاَثُونَ آيَةً شَفَعَتْ لِرَجُلٍ
>   حَتَّى غُفِرَ لَهُ وَهِيَ سُورَةُ تَبَارَكَ الَّذِي بِيَدِهِ الْمُلْكُ
>
> "Indeed there's a Surah in the Quran of thirty verses, which
>   intercedes for a man until he's forgiven. It is 'Tabaraka allathee
>   biyadihialmulk'"

Recorded in *Musnad Ahmed* and *Jami atTirmidhi* both have the same reporters.  However it's also weak because of the ambiguity (tadlis) of Qatadah and obscurity of Abbas alJoshami.

So, neither of these two *ahadith* can be taken to be solid and are considered suspicious.

Comment: Jazak allah kher brother, how do i know which hadiths are accurate an of a accurate narrator therefore i wouldn't be misguided?

Comment: You can do research and read through books of hadith narrators and their verdicts on reporting.  You can ask someone who has the means or tools to do it and they can tell you.  A lot of it is logical and related to our daily life when we receive news, do you take it all or not? Why or why not?  Same with hadith except it's more strict.  I can recommend two books to get you started.  First you should read is "Notes on Hadith" by Mahmud Tahhan.  And other is "an Introduction to Science of Hadith" by ibn as-Salah.  Both have been translated into English.  InshaAllah they should be good milestones

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the first reply that there are two further narrations which the responder did not mention.

> <sup>It is narrated via Ibn al-Mubarak in Al-Mustadrak ([2/540](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/4020)), which Al-Hakim classed Sahih to which Imam Dhahabi agreed upon, and via A'bd ar-Razzaq ([6025](https://shamela.ws/book/13174/6459)), which Shaykh Albani classed Hasan in Sahih at-Targhib (2/192-[3](https://shamela.ws/book/171/822#p1) - #[1475](https://shamela.ws/book/171/821)) - to which he also classed the abbreviated version of Sunan al-Kubra ([10479](https://shamela.ws/book/8361/14318)) as Hasan - that it is narrated in Mawquf form from Ibn Mas'ud:</sup>
>
> '(Angels) will come to a man in his grave; they will come to his feet and his feet will say: You have no power over us; he used to recite Surah al-Mulk. Then they will come to his chest or his stomach and it will say: You have no power over me; he used to recite Surah al-Mulk. Then they will come to his head and it will say: You have no power over me; he used to recite Surah al-Mulk. So, it is the Mani'ah (protector) that protects against the punishment of the grave and it is referred to in the Torah as Surah al-Mulk, whoever recites it by night has done a great deal and has done well.'

These are the words of Ibn Mas'ud, and one can have hope that this Hadith serves the purpose to recite Surah al-Mulk every night for the protection against the punishment of the grave.

Along with that protection, it should be said that to attain any reward of such magnitude, reciting Ayatul Kursi after every prayer, and with many other examples; that it is necessary to lead a life of a Muslim who fears Allah as much as he can, to do as He commands, and to seek therefore His forgiveness as well as rewards.

- Special mention:

> <sup>It is narrated in At-Tirmidhi ([2891](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2891)), which Abu I'sa classed Hasan, as well as by Shaykh Albani in Sahih Abu Dawud ([1265](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25881/1913)), that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*A Surah of the Qur'an containing thirty verses will intercede its reader*  [on the Day of Judgement] *till he will be forgiven. That is:* ***Blessed is He in Whose Hand is the sovereignty.***" [Surah ***[Al-Mulk](https://quran.com/al-mulk)***]